# Navbar does not collapse and center in Twitter Bootstrap 3 template

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I resize the window to mobile-size, the navbar does not collapse and the menu selection icon becomes unresponsive. The navbar fails to center as well. (Sorry my english is not the best).

Here is the page head:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf  -8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <!--The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

            <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

            <!--Bootstrap -->

            <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!--HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
            <!--WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->

            <!--[if lt IE 9]>

            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

            <![endif]-->

            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

            <!-- Optional theme -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

            <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Note CSS stylings:

```
            <style>

                #header{
                    text-align: center;
                    background-color: #add8e6;
                    width: 100%;
                    padding-bottom 20px;
                    top: 0;
                    position: fixed;
                }

                .menu {
                    background-color: white;
                    line-height:30px;
                    letter-spacing:1px;
                    width:100%;
                    border: 3px solid grey;
                }

                .content{
                    position: relative;
                }               

                .fixed{
                    position:fixed;
                    z-index:99;
                }               

                @media (min-width: 768px) {
                    .navbar .navbar-nav {
                        display: inline-block;
                        float: none;
                        vertical-align: top;                    
                        background-color:white;
                    }

                    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                }

                #details{
                    background-color: blue;
                }

                #footer{

                }

                #topContainer{
                    background-color: green;

                }


            </style>

        </head>


        <body >

            <header id="header">

                <br/>
                <div><h1 style="font-size:400%;"><strong>Du suchst eine g&uuml;nstige Mietwohnung in Jena?</strong></h1></div>
                <div><h3 style="font-size:200%;">Deine neue 3-Zimmer-Wohnung liegt im 20min entfernten Rothenstein</h3></div>
                <br/>

            </header>

            <div class="content contentContainer" id="topContainer">    



                <div class="content">   

                    <nav class="menu navbar-default">

                        <div class="container" >

                            <div class="navbar-header navbar-default" >

                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
                                data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" 
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>

                            </div>

                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#topContainer">Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#details">About</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#footer">Download The App</a></li>
                                    </ul>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </nav>  

                    </div>

                    <div id="topContainerContent">

                    </div>

                </div>



                <div class="content contentContainer" id="details"> 

                    <p> hallo</p>

                </div>



                <div class="content contentContainer" id="footer">  


                    <img  class="img-responsive" style="width: 150%; height: 900px;"src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/mann-der-laptop-im-b%C3%BCro-verwendet-37942789.jpg">
                    <p> hallo</p>
                    </img>
                </div>
```

Plugins:

```
                <!--jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <!--Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files asneeded -->
                <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

                <script>

                    $(".contentContainer").css("min-height",$(window).height());

                    var headerHeight = $('#header').height();



                    $('nav').css("marginTop",headerHeight);

                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
                            if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight) {
                            $('nav').addClass('fixed').css("top", -headerHeight);
                            $('body').css("marginTop",headerHeight);
                            }
                            else {
                                $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
                                $('body').css("marginTop","0");
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    $(window).resize(function(){

                        $(".contentContainer").css("min-height",$(window).height());

                        headerHeight = $('#header').height();

                        $('nav').css("marginTop",headerHeight);

                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
                                if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight) {
                                $('nav').addClass('fixed').css("top", -headerHeight);
                                $('body').css("marginTop",headerHeight);
                                }
                                else {
                                    $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
                                    $('body').css("marginTop","0");
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });


                </script>

            </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Step one: Remove this `</img>`. That is a self closing tag. I'll edit to add, it works fine with that removed. **See [This Demo Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/EthiJ8hjaS)**. Click the full screen preview icon to see it work (the one that looks like a monitor).

Comment: I'll also add that it works regardless of that incorrect closing tag. Do you have any errors in the console? Particularly any javascript errors or missing file errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 Things:

1. You should include jQuery before Bootstrap, in the `head` you include bootstrap CND but not jQuery, you are declaring jQuery at the end of the `body` tag. Move that declaration of bootstrap from the head after the jQuery declaration at the bottom
2. About the nav bar not responding:

You have content inside the `img` tag almost at the end of the file:

```
<img  class="img-responsive" style="width: 150%; height: 900px;"src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/mann-der-laptop-im-b%C3%BCro-verwendet-37942789.jpg">
    <p> hallo</p>
</img>
```

If you are using HTML5 then you should have this:

```
<img  class="img-responsive" style="width: 150%; height: 900px;"src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/mann-der-laptop-im-b%C3%BCro-verwendet-37942789.jpg" />
<p> hallo</p>
```

Or in XHTML this:

```
<img  class="img-responsive" style="width: 150%; height: 900px;"src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/mann-der-laptop-im-b%C3%BCro-verwendet-37942789.jpg"></img>
<p> hallo</p>
```

Dont place content inside the `img` tag.

3. About centering the nav bar:

Include this in your CSS:

```
div.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  line-height: 10px; /* There is a little space appearing at the
                        bottom, you can adjust it with this value */
  text-align: center;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tLxneqkb/1/

Answer (score 1):

As far as the centering goes you're using `menu` in lieu of `navbar` (the default) so your CSS won't work since you're using the following:

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;                    
        background-color:white;
      }
     .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
     }
 }
```

You also have `navbar-default` mixed with your `navbar-header` which is why your `navbar` isn't holding the white background under 768px.

The menu not opening has been addressed by others as far as the dependency order.

```js
$(".contentContainer").css("min-height", $(window).height());

var headerHeight = $('#header').height();



$('nav').css("marginTop", headerHeight);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight) {
      $('nav').addClass('fixed').css("top", -headerHeight);
      $('body').css("marginTop", headerHeight);
    } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
      $('body').css("marginTop", "0");
    }
  });
});

$(window).resize(function() {

  $(".contentContainer").css("min-height", $(window).height());

  headerHeight = $('#header').height();

  $('nav').css("marginTop", headerHeight);

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight) {
        $('nav').addClass('fixed').css("top", -headerHeight);
        $('body').css("marginTop", headerHeight);
      } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
        $('body').css("marginTop", "0");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #add8e6;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom 20px;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
.menu.navbar-default {
  background: white;
  line-height: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid grey;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
#details {
  background-color: blue;
}
#footer {} #topContainer {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header id="header">
  <br/>
  <div>
    <h1 style="font-size:400%;"><strong>Du suchst eine g&uuml;nstige Mietwohnung in Jena?</strong></h1>

  </div>
  <div>
    <h3 style="font-size:200%;">Deine neue 3-Zimmer-Wohnung liegt im 20min entfernten Rothenstein</h3>

  </div>
  <br/>
</header>
<div class="content contentContainer" id="topContainer">
  <div class="content">
    <nav class="menu navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#topContainer">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#details">About</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#footer">Download The App</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="topContainerContent"></div>
</div>
<div class="content contentContainer" id="details">
  <p>hallo</p>
</div>
```